# Swift for iOS: change array order and populate Picker

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uipickerview

I am trying to write an photography app in Swift for iOS that establishes equivalent exposure settings for a specified ƒ-stop and shutter speed. There are several downstream parts to writing this app that I have not reached yet (thus you won't see the code for obvious components, like user input or shutter speed). What I need help with is how to change the order of an array, based on the (ultimately) user-defined input value.

I was able to successfully achieve this in Playground, but when I try to apply it to the ViewController.swift to populate a Picker, I run into problems.

This is my Playground code:

```
var setƒstop = 1.4
var ƒstopout = [Double]()

func changeRange(inout setƒstop: (Double), inout ƒstopout: [Double]) {

if setƒstop == 1.0 {
    ƒstopout = [1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128]
} else if setƒstop == 1.4 {
    ƒstopout = [1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1]
} else if setƒstop == 2.0 {
    ƒstopout = [2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4]
} else if setƒstop == 2.8 {
    ƒstopout = [2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2]
} else if setƒstop == 4.0 {
    ƒstopout = [4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8]
} else if setƒstop == 5.6 {
    ƒstopout = [5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4]
} else if setƒstop == 8.0 {
    ƒstopout = [8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6]
} else if setƒstop == 11.0 {
    ƒstopout = [11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8]
} else if setƒstop == 16.0 {
    ƒstopout = [16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11]
} else if setƒstop == 22.0 {
    ƒstopout = [22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16]
} else if setƒstop == 32.0 {
    ƒstopout = [32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22]
} else if setƒstop == 44.0 {
    ƒstopout = [44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32]
} else if setƒstop == 64.0 {
    ƒstopout = [64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44]
} else if setƒstop == 88.0 {
    ƒstopout = [88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64]
} else if setƒstop == 128.0 {
    ƒstopout = [128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88]
}
}

changeOrder(&setƒstop, &ƒstopout)


println(ƒstopout)
println(ƒstopout[0])
```

And this is my ViewController.swift code:

```
import UIKit

var setƒstop = 1.4
var ƒstopout = [Double]()

func changeRange(inout setƒstop: (Double), inout ƒstopout: [Double]) {

if setƒstop == 1.0 {
    ƒstopout = [1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128]
} else if setƒstop == 1.4 {
    ƒstopout = [1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1]
} else if setƒstop == 2.0 {
    ƒstopout = [2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4]
} else if setƒstop == 2.8 {
    ƒstopout = [2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2]
} else if setƒstop == 4.0 {
    ƒstopout = [4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8]
} else if setƒstop == 5.6 {
    ƒstopout = [5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4]
} else if setƒstop == 8.0 {
    ƒstopout = [8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6]
} else if setƒstop == 11.0 {
    ƒstopout = [11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8]
} else if setƒstop == 16.0 {
    ƒstopout = [16,22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11]
} else if setƒstop == 22.0 {
    ƒstopout = [22,32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16]
} else if setƒstop == 32.0 {
    ƒstopout = [32,44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22]
} else if setƒstop == 44.0 {
    ƒstopout = [44,64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32]
} else if setƒstop == 64.0 {
    ƒstopout = [64,88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44]
} else if setƒstop == 88.0 {
    ƒstopout = [88,128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64]
} else if setƒstop == 128.0 {
    ƒstopout = [128,1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88]
}
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    changeRange(&setƒstop, &ƒstopout)
}

var arrayƒstop = ["\(ƒstopout[0])","\(ƒstopout[1])","\(ƒstopout[2])"] // etc. A truncated array is being used here for testing purposes.

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayƒstop.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return arrayƒstop[row]
}
}
```

I have tried several variations on this, but this is the only version I don't get a compile error with. Instead, when I try to run the simulator, it crashes with the error:

```
fatal error: Array index out of range
(lldb)
```

Meaning that the `var arrayƒstop` is not populating with the `ƒstopout` values per the `func changeRange`, instead referencing `var ƒstopout = [Double]()`.

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may make a suggestion:

```
extension Array {
    func rotated(steps : Int) -> [T] {
        return [T]( self[steps..<self.count] + self[0..<steps] )
    }
}

func indexOf<T: Equatable>(ary : [T], theItem : T) -> Int? {
    for (i, obj) in enumerate(ary) {
        if obj == theItem {
            return i
        }
    }
    return nil
}


let ƒstops = [1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128]

let ƒstopout = ƒstops.rotated( indexOf(ƒstops, setƒstop) ?? 0 )
```

This'll wipe out your extremely perilous and error prone conditional if-then thunka-thunkas.

Then in your view you do something like:

```
var arrayƒstop = ƒstopout.map { "\($0)" }
```

Generally speaking you should never hard code an array index.

Comment: Thank you. That worked great.

Regarding your suggestion of
    `var arrayƒstop = ƒstopout.map { "\($0)" }`
and @Jacobson Talom's suggestion of 
    `let arrayƒstop = ƒstopout.map { String(stringInterpolationSegment: $0) }`
These are both essentially different ways of expressing the same thing, correct?

Comment: Yeah they do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning `arrayƒstop` with fixed numbers, try using a `for-loop` or:

```
let arrayƒstop = ƒstopout.map { String(stringInterpolationSegment: $0) }
```

Because you're converting a `Double` to a `String` you'll need to give it a format like: `String(format: "%.1f", $0)` or use `stringInterpolationSegment` as shown in the example.

Answer (score 0):

your `ƒstopout` array is empty this is why it is resulting this crash.
you should initialize `arrayƒstop` after the call of `changeRange` method where it seems that you initialize its data there.

After that just reload the data of your pickerView.

To be sure of what i am saying, initialize your `ƒstopout` when you declare it in this way for example:

```
var ƒstopout = [1,1.4,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22,32,44,64,88,128]
```

and you will not have the crash.